# How to use a variable's value as another variable's name in bash

Tags: bash

I want to declare a variable, the name of which comes from the value of another variable, and I wrote the following piece of code:

```
a="bbb"
$a="ccc"
```

but it didn't work. What's the right way to get this job done?

Comment: If you are on Bash 5+ the better solution is nearly always an associative array. The duplicate has several demonstrations of this.

Answer (score 70):

`eval` is used for this, but if you do it naively, there are going to be nasty escaping issues. This sort of thing is generally safe:

```
name_of_variable=abc

eval $name_of_variable="simpleword"   # abc set to simpleword
```

This breaks:

```
eval $name_of_variable="word splitting occurs"
```

The fix:

```
eval $name_of_variable="\"word splitting occurs\""  # not anymore
```

The ultimate fix: put the text you want to assign into a variable. Let's call it `safevariable`. Then you can do this:

```
eval $name_of_variable=\$safevariable  # note escaped dollar sign
```

Escaping the dollar sign solves all escape issues. The dollar sign survives verbatim into the `eval` function, which will effectively perform this:

```
eval 'abc=$safevariable' # dollar sign now comes to life inside eval!
```

And of course this assignment is immune to everything. `safevariable` can contain `*`, spaces, `$`, etc. (The caveat being that we're assuming `name_of_variable` contains nothing but a valid variable name, and one we are free to use: not something special.)

Comment: So the `$safevariable` is the `$safe_target_value` to assign the variable name saved in `$name_of_variable` ?

Comment: `eval $name_of_variable="word\ splitting\ occurs"`  also works

Answer (score 64):

You can use `declare` and `!`, like this:

```
John="nice guy"
programmer=John
echo ${!programmer} # echos nice guy
```

Second example:

```
programmer=Ines
declare $programmer="nice gal"
echo $Ines # echos nice gal
```

Comment: Hi Flimm. Is it possible with arrays ? Something like `echo "${!array[1]}"` ?

Comment: @leaf: Maybe the `-a`-option of `declare` helps? See `declare --help`, and test for yourself.

Comment: It is nice gesture to say such nice things about your colleagues :D:D

Comment: Just a note, this will not work inside a function, for that I found KAz' eval solution to work.

Comment: Bash docs call the `${!var_name}` form "indirect expansion": https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: @Mr.Developerdude Confirmed this approach works inside functions with bash `3.2.57(1)-release`

Answer (score 20):

This might work for you:

```
foo=bar
declare $foo=baz
echo $bar
baz
```

or this:

```
foo=bar
read $foo <<<"baz"
echo $bar
baz
```

Comment: correct, better to use declare over eval (security reasons)

Comment: @meso_2600 declare does not behave the same way as assignment, because it will change the scope of the variable to the local one (you won't be able to modify a variable from a parent scope with declare, unless you declare it as a global variable).

Comment: your second answer is great. no subshell spawned. cheers.

Comment: @niieani: According to `declare --help`, the `-g` option to `declare` always declares a global variable.

Comment: @GolarRamblar that's correct. I didn't state otherwise, unless you're referring to something else?

Comment: I really like the `read` idea, cheers mate

Answer (score 9):

You could make use of [`eval`](http://ss64.com/bash/eval.html) for this.
Example:

```
$ a="bbb"
$ eval $a="ccc"
$ echo $bbb
ccc
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the value of the variable instead of setting it you can do this

```
var_name1="var_name2"
var_name2=value_you_want
eval temp_var=\$$var_name1
echo "$temp_var"
```

You can read about it here [indirect references](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html).

Answer (score -3):

You can assign a value to a variable using simple assignment using a value from another variable like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#variable one
a="one"

echo "Variable a is $a"
#variable two with a's variable
b="$a"

echo "Variable b is $b"

#change a
a="two"
echo "Variable a is $a"
echo "Variable b is $b"
```

The output of that is this:

```
Variable a is one
Variable b is one
Variable a is two
Variable b is one
```

So just be sure to assign it like this b="$a" and you should be good.

Comment: The question is how to indirect upon computed variable names, now how to assign expressions fixed variables.