# reference variable which is assigned value from another variable

Tags: shell

I have following shell script -

```
AWSZONE="central"
ENVIRONMENT="staging"
REMOTE_HOSTS_central_staging="172.31.7.59,172.31.3.151
NAME="REMOTE_HOSTS_${AWSZONE}_${ENVIRONMENT}"
echo "Using following agents: ${NAME}"
```

When executing I get following output -

```
Using following agents: REMOTE_HOSTS_central_staging
```

Though I would like to get output -

```
Using following agents: 172.31.7.59,172.31.3.151
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: eval "NAME=\$REMOTE_HOSTS_${AWSZONE}_${ENVIRONMENT}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use a variable's value as other variable's name in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-other-variables-name-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the echo to

```
echo "Using following agents: ${!NAME}"
```

And it should be OK.

Comment: works well, is there a special name for using negation symbol before variable name?

Comment: Its called indirect expansion. It is mentioned in the bash man pages under Parameter Expansion :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AWSZONE="central"
ENVIRONMENT="staging"
REMOTE_HOSTS_central_staging="172.31.7.59,172.31.3.151"
NAME="REMOTE_HOSTS_${AWSZONE}_${ENVIRONMENT}"
eval "echo Using following agents: \$${NAME}"
```

**Output:**

```
Using following agents: 172.31.7.59,172.31.3.151
```

If you use bash, you can also use @LarsErik's answer.It is known as 
[Indirect Expansion](http://ahmed.amayem.com/bash-indirect-expansion-exploration/)