# Declaring variable programmatically

Tags: java, variables

Suppose I have a file with content:

```
I want to declare a variable called science.
I want to declare a variable called commerce.
```

Now I want to declare variables based on last word of each line in the above file. Eg:-

```
public static String SCIENCE;
public static String COMMERCE;
```

How can I achieve this? I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-other-variables-name-in-bash) tries to do the same thing with bash.

How could it be done in java?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. Is your program meant to output source code, or do something else? Also, what would the type of these variables be? (The source code you've described isn't valid at the moment.)

Comment: variables are supposed to be string type ... i forgot to mention that ... sry for inconvinience.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: can we do this :
 String aa = "bb";
String bb = "cc"
i.e. aa = cc
Is there a process to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally is not necessary to give a name to a variable but have the opportunity to retrieve that variable with a name.

Consider to store your variable in [`Map<String, Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the key is the name of your variable. A Map is:

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

A code similar to the following can help:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

...
// To store an object with a key myName
map.put("myName", obj);

...
// To retrieve an object with a key myName
Object obj = map.get("myName");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to declare the variable names in running time.
You can try another way:

```
Map<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
maps.put(the last word of each line, the value);
```

Get the value by the last word of each line:

```
maps.get(the last word of each line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create some sort of abstract class or interface that represents the variable. Then you could have it initialized by converting a string into code using something like this [Convert String to Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code).

Comment: From what it sounds like what you want to do you could just have alot of strings converted to code

Comment: this answer may solve the issue... I will try and let you know ... thanks anyway.