# Find and replace string (from list of string) in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm wondering how to implement function which will find and replace string in my bash script, eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 -eq 1 ] then
ListToReplace="'Static_value as Column1','Static_value2' as Column2"
Searching which query contain Column1, Column2 , then Somehow replace in queries...
else
do nothing.
fi

query="Select Column1, Column2 from dual"
run query
query2="Select Column3, Column1 from dual"
run query2
```

let's assume we will run script with variable 1, then `query` should look:

```
Select 'Static_value' as Column1,'Static_value2' as Column2  from dual
```

and `query2`:

```
Select Column3, Static_value as Column1 from dual
```

with variable 0 then:

```
Select Column1,Column2  from dual
Select Column3,Column1 from dual
```

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Please, fix the formatting and add missing single quotes.

Comment: One hint; the command `[` does not expect to see `then` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Replacement in the `bash` is quite simple, though I'm not sure why you need/want a list here:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="Select Column1, Column2 from dual"
query2="Select Column3, Column1 from dual"

if [ "${1:-0}" -eq 1 ]; then
    for VAR in query query2; do
        VAL=${!VAR}
        VAL=${VAL/Column1/Static_value as Column1}
        VAL=${VAL/Column2/\'Static_value2\' as Column2}
        eval $VAR=\$VAL
    done
fi

echo run $query
echo run $query2
```

The `VAL=${!VAR}` reads variable's value by name. The `eval $VAR=\$VAL` assigns variable's value by name. (See [here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-other-variables-name-in-bash).) The `${//}` expansion performs the replacement inside the value.