# Use substituted string as a command in shell script

Tags: shell, command-substitution

Given the variables listed below:

```
echo ${userupper}_PYTHON
# YTU_PYTHON
echo $YTU_PYTHON
# /home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python
echo $path
# foo.py
```

Now I'd like to execute `/home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python foo.py` with `userupper` and `path`. I tried `$(${userupper}_PYTHON) $path` but it ends up with error messages including:

> YTU_PYTHON: not found
>   foo.py: not found

It seems like it takes `$(${userupper}_PYTHON)` as bare `YTU_PYTHON` rather than expected `$YTU_PYTHON`. How should I do to make it right?

---

Edits:

The suggested duplication should have solved my problem. However for some unknown reasons it's not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for user in ytu
do
  . /home/${user}/.profile
  userupper=$(echo ${user} | awk '{print toupper($0)}')
  userpython=${userupper}_PYTHON
  cd /home/${user}/H2-ML/crons
  for path in $(ls | grep ^${user}_.*_monthly_report.py$)
  do
    echo ${userpython}
    echo $path
    echo $YTU_PYTHON
    echo ${!userpython}
  done
done
```

The code chunk above returns:

> YTU_PYTHON
>   ytu_clinic249_monthly_report.py
>   /home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python
>   send_monthly_reports.sh: 14: send_monthly_reports.sh: Bad substitution

, which makes me so confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable's value as another variable's name in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-another-variables-name-in-bash)

Comment: @Biffen I really appreciate your suggestion and that indeed should have solved my problem. However somehow it's not. Please consider looking at my edits and giving me some feedbacks. Thank you.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- *I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!* -- will be eventually relevant (once you've fixed other issues).

Comment: Also see the various quoting bugs identified by http://shellcheck.net/. And don't trust `echo` to tell you the truth -- if you want robust logging, use `bash -x` / `set -x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
command=${userupper}_PYTHON
echo ${!command} $path # ommit echo if you want to execute command
```

in your case it echos:

```
/home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python foo.py
```

Here is [link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that might be useful if you want to write bash scripts. You should not parse `ls` output in the nutshell.

You also create unnecessary new process, both lines do the same:

```
$(echo ${user} | awk '{print toupper($0)}')
${user^^} #paramenter expansion
```

Comment: That should have worked, but it is not. Please see my edits above. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ytu is that whole script what you pasted, because I don't see first line with interpreter #!/bin/bash for example

Comment: I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Other than that it's the whole script. If I shouldn't parse `ls` output then how do I loop through the files? Besides the error is not caused by parsing `ls`. BTW `${user^^}` works only on Ubuntu but not on MacOS.

Comment: "How do I loop through the files?" -- with a shell wildcard. `for path in "$user"_*_monthly_report.py; do`. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @ytu, ...btw, `${user^^}` works perfectly fine on MacOS if you install a modern bash (something you can do with Nix, MacPorts or Homebrew).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy in fact ${user^^} gives me "Bad substitution" on Ubuntu in a shell script... (but it works in interactive terminal).

Comment: BTW I thought it should be better to _not_ to assume what user's bash is when developing, no?

Comment: @ytu, that would be the case if you used a `#!/bin/sh` script (or ran `sh myscript`, explicitly asking to run it with a POSIX sh interpreter), but that's *not a bash script*. Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` for bash.

Comment: @ytu, and correct, it's better not to assume. I prefix my scripts with something like `case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.0 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;; esac` -- that way you're not *assuming*, but *ensuring*. Bash 4.0 is came out in 2009 -- there's no excuse for running anything prior today. (Apple ships 3.2, a series from 2006, because they aren't willing to agree with the license for modern versions -- but if they don't change that policy, their release will just get more and more out-of-date in perpetuity).