# Why can't a string variable be evaluated as a command when using ${!variable}?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

This is somehow related to [Use substituted string as a command in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53116898/6666231) I asked last year. That accepted answer worked nicely.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for user in ytu
do
  cd /home/${user}/H2-Data/crons
  for path in "$user"_*_monthly_report.py
  do
    if [ -e $path ]
    then
      . ../../.profile
      userpython=${user^^}_PYTHON
      echo ${!userpython} $path
    else
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

This echos what I expected:

> /home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python ytu_clinic217_monthly_report.py
>   /home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python ytu_clinic226_monthly_report.py

However, by simply changing `${user^^}_PYTHON` to `$YTU_PYTHON`, which should be exactly the same in this case, the bash script now echos:

> ytu_clinic217_monthly_report.py
>   ytu_clinic226_monthly_report.py

I even tried `userpython=/home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python` but that ends up the same. That said, if I `echo $userpython`, I can still get */home/ytu/anaconda3/bin/python* in the latter cases.

I wonder why can't `userpython` be evaluated anymore by simply assigning the variable explicitly, and how can I make it right?

Comment: `${user^^}_PYTHON` expands to `YTU_PYTHON`, which is then the value of `$userpython`. If you use `$YTU_PYTHON`, which is a variable that doesn't exist, `$userpython` contains the empty string. The equivalent to what you have would be `userpython=YTU_PYTHON` (notice lack of `$`).

Comment: Run your script with `set -x` to see what gets set where.