# shell , single line if statement with variable assignment error

Tags: bash

```
user="none"
noneexist="false"
id -u $user > /dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -eq 0]]; then ${user}exist="true"; else echo "$user do not exist"; fi
-bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
-bash: syntax error near `;'
```

I am receiving this error, not sure what is wrong with my statement.

Comment: Check out [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), which helpfully points out issues like this.

Comment: `0]]` needs to be `0 ]]` - extra space!

Comment: Please don't edit your question to change it into something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space before your `;`

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then ${user}exist="true" ; else echo "$user do not exist" ; fi
```

You need a space on either side of your conditional brackets (`[[` and `]]`). All of the following will **not** work:

- `if [[$? -eq 0 ]] ; ...`
- `if [[ $? -eq 0]] ; ...`
- `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; ...`

Comment: thank you. i edited to post and appreciate if you can point the mistake ? I am not sure if i have to edit or post a new question.

Comment: @Pradeep check out the question that was marked as duplicate. It states that you need spaces before and after `[[` and `]]`. I'll add some more detail to my answer.

Comment: @Pradeep if you think I've solved your question, you can accept my answer with the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: @Pradeep, I see you're running into another issue. You won't be able to get an answer for that issue on this question thread; you'll have to open another one. However, this new question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9715739/6246128. There are many ways to do this, I prefer `read "$VARNAME" <<<"$VARVALUE"`

Comment: @Pradeep WRT the assignment problem, the shell doesn't really support dynamically-named variables (you can do it, but it's all kind of weird and klugy). I'd recommend backing up and asking if there's a better way of accomplishing the end goal.