# Using variables from shell script for gnuplot

Tags: bash, shell, gnuplot

I try to plot several curves on a same plot using variables from a shell script. My problem is that I do not succeed in collecting the variables and use them in gnuplot.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for elem in AMD WALE SIM;
do
  echo $elem
  Utau_$elem=$(awk 'FNR==5{print $1}' file_$elem)
done
gnuplot -persist  <<-EOFMarker
list= "AMD WALE SIM"
plot for [i in list] "stat_".i u 1:($1/Utau_.i) @ title_i  
EOFMarker
```

This script aim at avoiding to write all the plot sentences but should have the same effect that the following :

```
 plot "stat_AMD" u 1:($1/Utau_AMD}) @title_AMD,\
"stat_WALE" u 1:($1/Utau_WALE}) @title_WALE,\
"stat_SIM" u 1:($1/Utau_SIM})  @title_SIM
```

I did not succeed in plotting anything and I am not sure that the link can be done between the value Utau_$elem for the bash script and Utau_.i from the gnuplot script. Does someone have an idea if it is possible and how can I code it ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You didn't write how you invoke your script. Perhaps `$1` is empty?

Comment: What made you think that `Utau_$elem=` works the way you think?

Comment: @user1934428. I run my script on a terminal with ./file.sh. $1 refers to the first column of the files stat_AMD, stat_WALE and stat_SIM. It is not empty.

Comment: @U.Windl. Thank you for your answer. I did not really understand what do you mean. Utau_$elem=$(awk 'FNR==5{print $1}' file_$elem) should take the value of awk 'FNR==5{print $1}' file_$elem which is a decimal number

Comment: @Martin7 If I try (in bash): `N=1;X$N=2`, then I get `If 'X1=2' is not ...`. So it does not set variable `X1`, and I guess that is what you tried (in other words).

Comment: @U.Windl. Yes I would like to have Utau_AMD, Utau_WALE and Utau_AMD. How can I do this ?

Comment: for dynamic variable names take a look at these Q&As: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/7366100), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9714902/7366100), [#3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222487/234539); alternatively, consider using an array, eg, `Utau[${elem}]=$(awk ...); "${Utau[${i}]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @markp-fuso, it works !

I just had to replace "($1/${Utau_fr[${i}]})" by "(column(1)/${Utau_fr[${i}]})" because the dollar signs are interpreted as starting a shell variable.