# How can I get an environment variable from a quoted string in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab-ci and i wanna package my artifact with specified VERSION which exported by previous stages, but the key of version value is generated with CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA, and i export it like this:

```sh
export COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION=${VERSION}
```

but i can't use it like

```sh
echo ${COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION}

or

 `echo '$COMMIT_'"${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"'_REVISION'`
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `echo "COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION"`?

Comment: @Cyrus that will out put "COMMIT_something_VERSION", but i want use this string as a  key of value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable's value as another variable's name in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-another-variables-name-in-bash), in particular the answer given by Flimm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below example help you:

```
$ foo=testvar

$ bar=testvalue

$ declare "someprefix_${foo}=${bar}"

# your variable
$ echo $someprefix_testvar
testvalue

# one way
$ eval echo '$'"someprefix_${foo}"
testvalue

# other way -  prints the contents of the real variable
$ out="someprefix_${foo}"
$ echo ${!out}
testvalue
```

`eval` : Execute arguments as a shell command.

`declare` : [declare](https://ss64.com/bash/declare.html) is a bash built-in command that allows you to update attributes applied to variables within the scope of your shell.

Refer : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection

**You need:**

```
$ declare  "COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION=${VERSION}"
$ out="COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION"
$ echo ${!out}
```

**Test Results:**

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=abcdef
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ VERSION=1.2.0
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ declare  "COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION=${VERSION}"
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ out="COMMIT_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}_VERSION"
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ echo ${!out}
1.2.0
```

Comment: See *reference* variable `declare -n`!