# Use a variable's value to name another variable in Bash

Tags: bash

So, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
while [ $n -le 7 ] 
do 
   char$1=somevalue 
   echo $char$1 
   n++ 
done
```

But even reading through the links below and trying declare or something like $char${!n}, I haven't been able to make it work...  Halp!  :)

I've already looked at:
[How to use a variable's value as another variable's name in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-another-variables-name-in-bash)
and
[Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/dynamic-variable-names-in-bash)

Thanks!

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find errors in your code.

Comment: It is possible to do what you are asking for, but it's messy and error-prone.  There are often  better ways.  For instance, instead of using variables `char1`, `char2`, `...`, use an array called `chars`.  For an improvement over `char_a`, `char_b`, `...`, use an associative array.  See [Arrays -Bash Hackers Wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays).

Comment: See [BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: If you've read those duplicates, how do you _not_ know how to use `printf -v "char$1" %s "somevalue"`?

Comment: ...as for the reference end, it's `var="char$n"; echo "${!var}"` -- you have to do the indirect reference for the whole name at once, not just for the part that's dynamic. But again, this is already demonstrated in the existing duplicates. There are *lots* of different answers attached to _Dynamic variable names in bash_; I have trouble believing you read it thoroughly and came away not knowing a single working approach.

Comment: Thank you @pjh for your useful insights!  I'm doing it as an array now, which is much simpler and the correct way to do what I need to do.